# Display 'figure' window from command line execution

Tags: windows, octave

I just started using octave and I'm having trouble showing 'figure' window from octave-cli.

Lets say I have a octave file called `C:\test\myfile.m`

```
figure(1);
plot(1,1);
eval 2+3;
```

When I run it in windows cmd

```
C:\Octave\Octave-4.0.0\bin\octave-cli C:\test\myfile.m
```

I get the result as

```
C:\Users\me> ans = 5
```

it didn't pop up a window showing the plot. However, If I were to run it using the octave(GUI), I am able to see this 'figure' window.

What am I missing here?

*Running on Windows 10 64-bit, GNU Octave 4.0*

Comment: Hi @carandraug, that solved the issue, but it causes the window to stop responding. Is there a more elegant way to bypass this?

Comment: have you tried --persistent? This should keep the window responsive

Comment: @Hibiki read the answer on the duplicate question and follow the link for the FAQ which has more details. My guess is that you are using fltk as graphics toolkit.